# Usar variable como nombre de columna

Tags: sql, sql-server, datatables

estoy creando una tabla temporal dentro de un SP que debe mostrar como resultado una tabla cuando se ejecuta, tengo variables que tienen los nombres del mesactual y del anterior, y quisiera que se usaran como nombres de las columnas ya que me marcan error. Actualmente está así:

declare @mesactual nvarchar(max) = DATENAME (month, GETDATE());
declare @mesanterior nvarchar(max) = DATENAME (month, dateAdd(month, -1, getdate()));

create table ReportTest(
id int not null identity (1,1),
policy_num nvarchar(max)
plan_name nvarchar(max),
name nvarchar(max),
lastname nvarchar(max),
@mesactual nvarchar(max),
@mesanterior nvarchar(max)
)

Me marca error cuando pongo las variables como nombre de columna, alguna solución para este detalle? :(

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Claro, no puedes usar variables como definición de nombres de columnas o tablas, el lenguaje no permite usar estás en una sentencia. Lo que sí puedes es construir una sentencia dinámica, es decir la consulta de creación armarla en una cadena y luego ejecutarla con `sp_executesql`, busca en el sitio por que esto ya se ha respondido varias veces.

Comment: Quieres crear tablas con el nombre del mes actual y anterior... Al final del año tendrás... 12 tablas más? en tres años tendrás 36 tablas más? Qué tiene de malo una sola tabla con una columna de fecha y un índice sobre esa columna?